# In logs I see KafkaTopicPartition cannot be used as a POJO; what does that mean?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Not an error but I do see this line that according to the message might effect performance:

```
2019-01-02 14:44:44,879 INFO  org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor             
- class org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.KafkaTopicPartition 
does not contain a setter for field topic
2019-01-02 14:44:44,879 INFO  org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor             
- Class class org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.KafkaTopicPartition 
cannot be used as a POJO type because not all fields are valid POJO fields, 
and must be processed as GenericType. Please read the Flink documentation on "Data Types & Serialization" 
for details of the effect on performance.
 2019-01-02 14:44:44,884 INFO  org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase  - No restore state for FlinkKafkaConsumer.
```

Is this something that I can/need to do about it ?

Answer (score 4):

This statement about types that cannot be used as POJO types is logged at INFO level rather than WARN because it's often not particularly relevant. But it does sometimes indicate classes that may be causing performance problems. This is because Flink is able to use its own, more performant serialization framework for POJO classes (classes with an empty default constructor and public fields, or public getters and setters), and otherwise falls back to Kyro.

If this were one of your application objects, and if you were going to be serializing and deserializing LOTS of them, then yes, this would be something to consider doing something about. But in this case, no. This is an internal object used by the various Flink/Kafka connectors, and it shouldn't be changed.